# Pandas check for nan values on same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database

With this dataframe :

```
  +----+------------+-----------+-----------+
    | id | first_name | last_name | full_name |
    +----+------------+-----------+-----------+
    |  1 | Bob        | smith     | nan       |
    |  2 | nan        | nan       | John doe  |
    |  3 | Ash        | Raf       | Ash Raf   |
    |  4 | Alice      | nan       | nan       |
    |  5 | nan        | Robert    | nan       |
    |  6 | nan        | nan       | nan       |
    +----+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I need either the first_name/last_name couple to be not nan OR the full_name to be not nan, so line 1, 2 and 3 are good, but line 4, 5 and 6 are not.

How can I find the bad lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print good ones:

```
m = ~df[['first_name', 'last_name']].isna().any(axis=1) | ~df['full_name'].isna()
print( df[m] )
```

Prints:

```
   id first_name last_name full_name
0   1        Bob     smith       NaN
1   2        NaN       NaN  John_doe
2   3        Ash       Raf   Ash_Raf
```

---

To find bad lines:

```
m = ~df[['first_name', 'last_name']].isna().any(axis=1) | ~df['full_name'].isna()
print( df[~m] )
```

Prints:

```
   id first_name last_name full_name
3   4      Alice       NaN       NaN
4   5        NaN    Robert       NaN
5   6        NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(~df.first.isnull() & ~df.last.isnull()) | (~df.full.isnull())]
```

Comment: FYI, this gives the good lines. For bad ones, just simply take the compliment: `df[~(conditions)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with  chain conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` and `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df = df[(df['first_name'].notna() & df['last_name'].notna()) | df['full_name'].notna()]
print (df)
   id first_name last_name full_name
0   1        Bob     smith       NaN
1   2        NaN       NaN  John doe
2   3        Ash       Raf   Ash Raf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.notna` and then all over axis 1:

```
df[df.notna().all(axis=1)]
```